# no graphics driver for 4650G with 20.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, graphics, display-resolution, amd-graphics

I'm planning to switch from Windows to Linux and I have installed 20.04 LTS on my new PC with AMD 4650G APU using integrated graphics card, everything booting up OK except the system wouldn't detect integrated graphics card. showing:
`llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 128 bits)`
as my graphics and the system can only use 1024x768 resolution.

I have very little knowledge about Linux and I couldn't find any information about this combination on the internet.

I'm kinda lost at this point and would like to ask for help, any related information will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Edited, sorry guys it was 20.04. I wrote this during middle of the night and made this silly mistake...

Comment: There's no 20.20 LTS version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu releases for desktop and servers use a *year.month* format, and no year has 20 months, so check you've actually installed Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm buying this APU now and I'm wondering how it runs on ubuntu as of now?

Answer (score 0):

When installing Proxmox 6.3 on an AMD 4650G CPU/APU and having no other GPU installed while running in UEFI-mode, this helped me:

Just select your the boot-option in the grub-menu (do not hit enter yet), hit `e` to edit the boot-settings and add `amdgpu.exp_hw_support=1` at the end of the `linux`-line. When that is done, press `F10` to progress. After that I was able to progress with my system, might work for Ubuntu too.